# What is a *.PODSPEC file?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm an iOS developer and I am really interested in all about PODSPEC file:

1. What is it used for?
2. Why do we need it?
3. What is it helpful for?

Thanks a lot guys.

Hope in this question we will collect enough info, cause I have not found a thing about it.

Comment: if you google "podspec" the first result is the [cocoapods website](http://cocoapods.org) which pretty much explains all of your questions

Comment: @wattson12 before I reached to open this question, I've found cocoapods site, but it doesn't answer the question, it already explains you how to install and use it. My question states to be a Wiki answer, which will help users who also do not understand its use, in a faster and more simple way. Just answer the question, if you do really know how to make it simple and clear for all those who does not really understand it.

Comment: there is no point of having a wiki here, the cocoapods website (combined with github page) already answers these questions and contains its own wiki, moving content here seems pointless

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the file extension for CocoaPods, which is distributed as a ruby gem. Which is available in [twitter](http://twitter.com/CocoaPods).

Also on [github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/The-podspec-format)

EDIT:

Cocoapods (http://cocoapods.org/) is a dependency management framework for XCode. It allows you to declaratively define project dependencies and have them included in the build of your project. It's like Apache Maven or Ruby Gems for XCode.

Why you need this?

As an iOS developer, you certainly use a lot of code made by others, in the shape of libraries. You may not remember, but how complicated would your life be if you had to implement everything from scratch?
Usually (since building static libraries manually is sooooo boring), you just add the library code into your project. But that has some disadvantages:
Code that could be somewhere else is stored in your repository, wasting space.
Sometimes, it’s hard to get a specific version of a library.
There’s no central place where you can see which libraries are available.
Finding a new version of a library and updating your project with it is boring and sometimes, painful.
Downloading libraries manually creates a tendency to perhaps make some changes to the downloaded code and just leaving it there (making updating harder, as you’ll need to merge the changes you made with the code you download for the next version).

Copied from : http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods

Comment: I would be very pleased if you would be more explicit and answer my questions. I think everyone can understand that this is the extension for CocoaPods:) Hope you will help the community.

Comment: I have updated few lines with a tutorial link. Everything I cant copy and paste :p

Comment: Thanks man, for me this is a +/- a good answer, following the link explains everything. ;)